# display data for every n-th data using clistview

Tags: php, yii, clistview

how can i display data for every let's say odd entry?
So first record Z, second record do Y, third record do Z, fourth do Y.
or lets say i get from model every nth record, and another that does n-1?

```
public function getNewItem()//for main page grids
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->order = 'posted_date DESC';
        $criteria->compare('product_status',"Y");
        $criteria->compare('product_approval_status',"Y");      
//????

        return new CActiveDataProvider( $this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
                'pagination'=>false,
        ));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this; depending on how complex your filtering needs to be;

First method you can modify your criteria compare to filter by only odd or even records like this

```
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->order = 'posted_date DESC';
        $criteria->compare('product_status',"Y");
        $criteria->compare('product_approval_status',"Y");

        $criteria->addCondition('MOD(id,2)=1','AND');
```

or any such condition to get the corresponding subset of records

Second method is to filter it in the partial file you use in the `CListView`, I use this method to usually add additional code not for filtering, for example you want to add a new row every forth element, For this use the `$index`and `$widget` variable made available in the [`itemView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#itemView-detail) attribute in the `CListView` call with something like this.

```
<?php if(($index)%6 == 0 || $index == 0 ){ ?>
     <div class="row">
<?php } ?>

  // Regular view rendering code
  // ...

 <?php if(($index+1)%6 == 0 || ($index+1) == $widget->dataProvider->itemCount){ ?>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Here I have used this to insert a new div for every 6 items in the list or if its the first/last item
This is useful for conditional rendering of items/ adding classes etc.